# VK video API in PHP

Tags: php, api, vk

I would like an API in PHP for the direct link to download videos from social network VK.

**Example:**

(VK video link)

```
$source = 'https://vk.com/video-51189706_456246056';
```

(Through the source, generate direct links to all available video qualities)

```
$720p = 'https://psv49-7.daxab.com/cs1-67v4.vkuservideo.net/p18/8835b7e86c59.720.mp4';

$480p = 'https://psv49-7.daxab.com/cs1-67v4.vkuservideo.net/p18/8835b7e86c59.720.mp4';
```

Is it possible in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have [an access token](https://vk.com/dev/access_token), all you have to do is to perform a POST request at [video.get method](https://vk.com/dev/video.get).

I am not familiar with PHP, but here is the simplest curl representation.

```
curl -X POST \
        -d 'v=5.92' \
        -d 'access_token=%YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN%' \
        -d 'videos=-51189706_456246056' \
        https://api.vk.com/method/video.get
```